# How can I match the xmlns:* attributes with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

How can I match the **xmlns:*** attributes with XSLT 1.0 ? Using a RDF document I tried:

```
<xs:template match="rdf:RDF">
(...)
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
(...)
</xsl:template>
```

but it doesn't seem to work for the **xmlns** attributes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The xmlns attributes aren't normal attributes, they are namespace declarations. You need to use the namespace axis to access them.

e.g.:

```
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::*">
   <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly, but have a look at the [`namespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#axes) axis:

```
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```